# Условие if/elseif php, как написать лучше?

Tags: php, условия

Есть кусок кода написанный мною, отрабатывает правильно, вместе с тем есть ощущение что можно написать лучше, подскажите пожалуйста как написать лучше если это возможно.

```
if(isset($filter_status) && !isset($filter_language)){
                if($this->getMkTime($item->created_at) >= $from && $this->getMkTime($item->created_at)<=$to && $item->order_status == $filter_status){
                    $data['orders'][] = $item;
                }
            }elseif(!isset($filter_status) && isset($filter_language)){
                if($this->getMkTime($item->created_at) >= $from && $this->getMkTime($item->created_at)<=$to && $item->lang == $filter_language){
                    $data['orders'][] = $item;
                }
            }elseif(isset($filter_status) && isset($filter_language)){
                if($this->getMkTime($item->created_at) >= $from && $this->getMkTime($item->created_at)<=$to && $item->order_status == $filter_status && $item->lang == $filter_language){
                    $data['orders'][] = $item;
                }
            }else{
                if($this->getMkTime($item->created_at) >= $from && $this->getMkTime($item->created_at)<=$to){
                    $data['orders'][] = $item;
                }
            }
```

Comment: я может не пойму чего, но вне зависимости от условий, он же выводит одно и тоже...
UPD: а все понял в чем дело)

Answer (score 1):

Ну эстетичнее было бы вынести условия

```
$this->getMkTime($item->created_at) >= $from && $this->getMkTime($item->created_at)<=$to
```

В отдельную переменную, 
Плюс `isset($filter_status)` как отдельную переменную и `isset($filter_language)` как отдельную переменную.
Была бы проверка типа `if (a&b) elseif(a&!b)`, а саму структуру проверок можно сделать как:

```
if(a){
    if(b){} 
    else{}
}
else{ 
    if(b) 
    else{}
}
```

Но это вкусовщина же!

Answer (score 0):

На эту тему прочитайте 10-11 главы "Совершенный код" (с) Стив Макконнелл

Почему у Вас для всех условий одинаковый вывод я не понимаю, но основной затык в читаемости, я бы сделал так. Кода больше, но прочитать легче.

И еще у Вас недоработка в структуре If в этой части условия `$this->getMkTime($item->created_at) >= $from && $this->getMkTime($item->created_at)<=$to` Это условие всегда одинаково и его можно вынести на самый верх

```
$filterLanguage = isset($filter_language) ? $filter_language : null;
$filterStatus = isset($filter_status) ? $filter_status : null;
$itemCreatedTime = $this->getMkTime($item->created_at);
$filterSearchFromTime = $from;
$filterSearchToTime = $to;

$searchByStatus = ($filterStatus !== null);
$searchByLanguage = ($filterLanguage !== null);
$itemTimeMatchFilterTime = ($itemCreatedTime >= $filterSearchFromTime && $itemCreatedTime <= $filterSearchToTime);

$itemStatusMatchFilter = ($item->order_status == $filter_status);
$itemLanguageMatchFilter = ($item->lang == $filter_language);

if ($itemTimeMatchFilterTime) {
    if ($searchByStatus && !$searchByLanguage && $itemStatusMatchFilter)
        $data['orders'][] = $item;
    else if (!$searchByStatus && $searchByLanguage && $itemLanguageMatchFilter)
        $data['orders'][] = $item;
    else if ($searchByStatus && $searchByLanguage && $itemStatusMatchFilter && $itemLanguageMatchFilter)
        $data['orders'][] = $item;
    else
        $data['orders'][] = $item;
}
```

P.S. А вообще у Вас вся логика сводится к

```
$itemCreatedTime = $this->getMkTime($item->created_at);
$filterSearchFromTime = $from;
$filterSearchToTime = $to;
$itemTimeMatchFilterTime = ($itemCreatedTime >= $filterSearchFromTime && $itemCreatedTime <= $filterSearchToTime);

if ($itemTimeMatchFilterTime) {
         $data['orders'][] = $item;
    }
```

То есть фильтры Статус и Язык бесполезны, так как результат от них не зависит. Не думаю, что это именно то, чего вы хотели

Answer (score -1):

Ну это сугубо моя мысль:

```
$gt_time = $this->getMkTime($item->created_at);
$ords = $item->order_status;
$lang = $item->lang;

if ( ($gt_time >= $from && $gt_time <= $to && $ords == $filter_status) || ($gt_time >= $from && $gt_time <= $to && $lang == $filter_language) || ($gt_time >= $from && $gt_time<=$to && $ords == $filter_status && $lang == $filter_language) ) {

  $data['orders'][] = $item;

} elseif ($gt_time >= $from && $gt_time <= $to) {

  $data['orders'][] = $item;

}
```

Comment: А зачем тогда elseif если операция внутри та-же самая?

Comment: ну да перепуточки, можно впихнуть в 1 все